# How to dis/enable dynamically created comboboxes in an order

Tags: java, forms, jsf-2, primefaces

We have a complex form where comboboxes are dynamically created and than populated by the database (lets say 5). The problem is that they have to be selected in order: only the first one should be enabled at the beginning, changeing its values will enable the next one and so on. I understood the example at the [Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprSelect.jsf), but there the form is static.

Here is some pseudocode of the iteration:

```
<p:dataGrid ... >
 <p:column ... >

  <p:selectOneMenu id="WhichIdToChoose?" disabled="when?" ...>
    <f:selectItems value="#{Some.value}" />
    <p:ajax update="chosenIds?" listener="#{bean.handleStateChanged}" /> 
  </p:selectOneMenu>

 </p:column>
</p:dataGrid>
```

So the problem is that I dont know **how to find the first cb and enable it** and **how to disable the others** and how to **reenable them based on their dynamic ids and order of appearance**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the data grid iterates over a list of object I suppose you could do something like this:

```
 <p:dataGrid id="dataGrid" var="var" value="#{bean.listOfThins}">
    <p:column ... >
      <p:selectOneMenu value="{var.selectedValue} disabled="#{var.disabled}">
          <f:selectItems value="#{Some.value}" />
          <p:ajax update="dataGrid" listener="#{bean.handleStateChanged(var)}" /> 
      </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:column>
 </p:dataGrid>
```

This way in handleStateChanged you know exactly what combo changed and what cb to enable in the list. Also, you cand update the entire dataGrid so you don't need to know the exact id.